# Asymptotic Normality of one-sample U-statistic in van der Vaart

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, weak-convergence

I have a question related to the proof of Theorem 12.3 (asymptotic normality of the one-sample U-statistic) in Van der Vaart "Asymptotic Normality" [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ocg2AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT324&lpg=PT324&dq=in%20view%20of%20the%20permutation%20symmetry%20of%20the%20kernel&source=bl&ots=Rm4Ty2JJ7L&sig=MggIqzTLD6I-vQfDKj2ydVpGV28&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqnKec7p_KAhUKWxQKHVnGCDMQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=in%20view%20of%20the%20permutation%20symmetry%20of%20the%20kernel&f=false).

> My question is related to the point in which the author says that
>   $$(1) \sqrt{n}(U-\theta-\hat{U})\rightarrow_p$$ provided that
>   $$(2) \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{Var(U)}{Var({\hat{U}})}= 1$$

In order to show (1) the author suggests to apply Theorem 11.2 in the same book. This theorem states that if (2) is satisfied then $$(3) \frac{U-\theta}{\sqrt{Var(U)}}-\frac{\sqrt{n}\hat{U}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi_1}}\rightarrow_p 0$$

In addition, we know that

$$
(4) \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n Var(U)= r^2\xi_1
$$

> My question is: how can (3) + (4) imply (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess $U$ and $\hat{U}$ have subscripts $n$ suppressed? (3) says 
\begin{align*}
\frac{U-\theta}{\sqrt{VarU}} - \frac{\sqrt{n}\hat{U}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi}} = 
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{nVarU}}(U-\theta - \frac{\sqrt{nVarU}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi}}\hat{U}) \to_p 0
\end{align*} 
The vector $(\sqrt{nVarU},\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{nVarU}}(U-\theta - \frac{\sqrt{nVarU}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi}}\hat{U}))\to_p (\sqrt{r^2\xi},0)$ (the first component is nonrandom), so the continuous mapping theorem with the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ implies $\sqrt{n}(U-\theta - \frac{\sqrt{nVarU}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi}}\hat{U}) \to_p 0$, or
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(U-\theta - \hat{U}) + \sqrt{n}(1-\frac{\sqrt{nVarU}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi}})\hat{U} \to_p 0.
\end{align}

(This is just a long way of saying if $\alpha_n\to_p \alpha, \beta_n\to\beta$ for RVs $\{\alpha_n\}$ and scalars $\{\beta_n\}$, then $\beta_n\alpha_n\to_p \alpha\beta$.) Using this same continuous mapping argument, the assumption that $(1-\frac{\sqrt{nVarU}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi}})\to 0$, and the asymptotic normality (mentioned in your link) of $\sqrt{n}\hat{U}$, $\sqrt{n}(1-\frac{\sqrt{nVarU}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi}})\hat{U} \to_p 0$. By Slutsky's lemma,
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(U-\theta - \hat{U}) + \sqrt{n}(1-\frac{\sqrt{nVarU}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi}})\hat{U} - \sqrt{n}(1-\frac{\sqrt{nVarU}}{\sqrt{r^2\xi}})\hat{U} \to_D 0.
\end{align}
Convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability, so $\sqrt{n}(U-\theta - \hat{U})\to_p 0$.

Comment: "Convergence in probability implies weak convergence so multiplying the above by $\sqrt{n}VarU$, invoking Slutsky' theorem, and equivalence of convergence in distribution and probability for a nonrandom limit": could you do it step by step?

Comment: sure, also simplified some.